# Change text get by API depending on the language in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

In my app I have to display a text that I get through an API call in two different languages. I've use the i18n process to translate fixed text in the app but I can't use the json file since I get the two texts from my API.

```
<div class="explore-short-descr-text explore-info-content-padding">
   getShortDescription()
</div>
```

```
getShortDescription(){
    return this.lngService.selected == 'it' ? this.xploreItem.shortDescription : this.xploreItem.shortDescriptionEng;
}
```

This's how I'm doing right now, but I was wondering if there's a better way to do that.

Comment: By `I use the i18n process` you mean the angular i18n feature with aot translation? If so, you could mimic dynamic translations by using a dictionary structure (e.g. one per language) and grab it from there. Or maybe have translations in a db and receive already translated texts (passing in the language upon request).

Comment: How can I refer to the exact dictionary item from the template ?

Comment: From the template you'd probably need to have a dictionary (if you import it, you need to assign it to a local variable in the ts) with locales as keys and the actual dictionary being nested and then something like `translations[language][token]`. If possible I'd recommend to evaluate the translation only once though (when in subscribe of http request) and assign the translation to an object property (of xploreItem) or a separate property.

Answer (score 0):

use `ngx-translate`. install it - `npm install @ngx-translate/core --save`
and then, in `AppModule`:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  if (environment.simulateTranslations) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
  } else {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, `${environment.apiBase}/translations`);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MsalModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateModule,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

and you should have separate json file for every language name like this: `en.json` `he.json` etc

this way you can load a different language json file and also decide rather to load it from server or from assets directory